# How to create object keys from array values in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

How to type following function in typescript so I get autocompletion & error prevention.

Using Typescript 4.7.4

```
// reference fn
function doSomething(list) {

    const data = {};

    list.map(item => {
        data[item] = 'value type string|number|bool|null'   
    });

    return data;
}

// calling it like
const data = doSomething([
    'phone_number',
    'customer_email'
]);

// get IDE autocomplete here (for only properties inside data)
console.log(data.phone_number);
console.log(data.customer_email);

// typescript yell when try to access invalid properties
console.log(data.phone_numbersss);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it provided the array being used is effectively a compile-time constant at the point of the function call (so TypeScript knows what its values are). Otherwise, TypeScript doesn't know what the array contents are and will have to assume any string. There are at least two ways that constraint can be satisfied:

1. You can say an array is constant directly by applying a [constant assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to it:

   ```typescript
   const names = ["phone_number", "customer_email"] as const;
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. You can use an array literal at the point of the call, and use a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) for the parameter's type (more below).

Once we know that the array's contents are a compile-time constant to TypeScript, we can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) to map an array that extends `string[]` to an object with the array elements as keys and the desired property types:

```typescript
type DoSomethingResult<T extends readonly string[]> = {
    [Key in T[number]]: string | number | boolean | null;
};
```

Implementing the function requires creating the object (rather than an array) and giving the properties some value; I've chosen `null`:

```typescript
function doSomething<T extends readonly string[]>(list: [...T]): DoSomethingResult<T> {
    // Variadic tuple type −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
    return Object.fromEntries(list.map((key) => [key, null])) as DoSomethingResult<T>;
}
```

Here's the call:

```typescript
const data = doSomething([
    "phone_number",
    "customer_email"
]);
```

Then all of your given test cases work.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gZTgWwsAFgSwHYHMBKEAzgK4A2wAPACpQQAewE2AJkVAE4QCGLc2ZEFCLAOOXAG0AugD4oAXigBvAFBR1UCQGkIQnFGoTsJZACMIHKVIBcw0eKgAfKMbMWnUU3Dhke2D8ZkZADcKgC+oQBmJNgAxsCY-FB8SKgY4jR0jMxsnDx8AkIiYnjSMgAUZJgithIAdA3UUgCUtvCpaFh4hKQUNHKqGnnAJBz+APKmAFYQ8XWRHCgAotj2xJXVwHXI3GDl5QDWus0KchJHIAA0LuRkLSfc7O0oneI95FTUMqFhKiqx-BEyW4wG4CmSiBe6Tw5Qkag0ACIwOh+BAAPqucwcBGXeHqBGxEgiF4cNEQHaYMgIlQtUIqAD09KgAHE0FAAJIwJZQbgkYBwAHIMC+JhQdAWaDlSJwDhQfiCKBgRaQDgJYhQHBETAsaAsEHcZr-QE+CB1MhwXDlPWgurI1EYkxY5qhAHYIgms0Wq36uqE4moUnk7iU51-RlQJYcRayx7JYiYLgsKDS2U4ABu3CqSaVcBVaqIRrdHvNlut3FtKOw6MxFiIdedQA)

Note that the array has to be an array literal; this won't work:

```typescript
// WON'T WORK AS DESIRED
const names = [
    "phone_number",
    "customer_email"
];
const data = doSomething(names);
```

TypeScript infers the type of the array to be `string[]`, not `["phone_number", "customer_email"]`. (It would work if you added an `as const` on the array.)

---

If you had to support versions of TypeScript that didn't have variadic tuple types (introduced in v4.0), you'd use the `as const` version instead:

```typescript
function doSomething<T extends readonly string[]>(list: T): DoSomethingResult<T> {
    // Using `T` directly as the type −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
    return Object.fromEntries(list.map((key) => [key, null])) as DoSomethingResult<T>;
}
// ...
const data = doSomething([
    "phone_number",
    "customer_email"
] as const);
//^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground link using v3.9.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gZTgWwsAFgSwHYHMBKEAzgK4A2wAPACpQQAewE2AJkVAE4QCGLc2ZEFCLAOOXAG0AugD4oAXigBvAFBR1UCQGkIQnFGoTsJZACMIHKVIBcw0eKgAfKMbMWnUU3Dhke2D8ZkZADcKgC+oQBmJNgAxsCY-FB8SKgY4jR0jMxsnDx8AkIiYnjSMgAUZJgittQAlLbwqWhYeISkFDRyqhp5wCQc-gDypgBWEPEAdJEcKACi2PbEldXAk8jcYOXlANa6dQpyEnsgADQu5GRSdQfc7E0oLeLt5FTUMqFhKiqx-CLJ3GA3AUyUQj3SeHKEjUGgARGB0PwIAB9VzmDiw04w9Sw2IkESPDjIiAbTBkWEqKRQO5QX7YER1UIqAD0zKgAHE0FAAJIwObUkjAOC-ZBgXxMKDoCzQcqROAcKD8QRQMCzSAcBLEKA4IiYFjQFiA7h1H5-HwQSZkOC4cqGoGTBFI1EmdGM03082W622o2TPEE1BEkncMlullsuYcWYKmn63VcFhQOUKnAAN24VUTqrg6s1RHdRE9Vptdu4DsR2BRaIsRFrjKAA)

Comment: Wonderful, but is there any way not to use `as const`? because this is a react hook. doing it every time I use the hook doesn't look good.

Comment: @APu just use `(list: [...T])` instead of `(list: T)`. See [variadic tuple types docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - Wow, I did **not** know that trick. I'll fold it into the answer.

Comment: Thumbs up for that @captain-yossarianfromUkraine for this, You're welcome to edit the answer `T.J`. You've given an wonderful answer

Comment: @APu- On first glance, I don't think that's related to the solution above; it's just the usual issue with dynamic keys. But please provide a playground link replicating it and I'll see if I can help (either way).

Comment: Now I need to convert the value to int (number in JS) so want to add `toInt` method in the result, which should look like `setting.toInt(' key here (with auto completion) ')` @T.J.Crowder @
captain-yossarian from Ukraine can you please teach me how to do that?