# Generate object type with keys from actual data

Tags: typescript

I want to get some data from an API where I can specify in the query parameters which properties I want to get back:

http://fake.service.com/users?name&email&height

It then returns some data something like:

```
[{ name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@bob.com', height: '180cm' }, ...]
```

But the keys of the objects depend on the input, and I want to write my function in such a way that it is producing the object's types accordingly:

```
const res = await getUserInfo(['name', 'email', 'height']);
```

where `res` would be of type:

```
{
   name: string,
   email: string,
   height: string
}[]
```

But if you specified only e.g. `['name']`, then it would produce

```
{
   name: string,
}[]
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73591609/3001761?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: lodash has the `pick` method

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is in fact what i need, Thanks for the link, now there is a bit of digesting coming on my part on what is happening in this code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating through elements to return their types.

```
type UserKeys = 'name' | 'email' | 'height';

type User = {
  [K in UserKeys]: string;
};

async function getUserInfo(keys: UserKeys[]): Promise<User[]> {
  const queryString = keys.join('&');
  const apiUrl = `http://fake.service.com/users?${queryString}`;
  
  // Make your API call here and get the response
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  const data = await response.json();

  // Transform the data to match the User type
  const result: User[] = data.map((item: any) => {
    const user: Partial<User> = {};
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      user[key] = item[key];
    });
    return user as User;
  });

  return result;
}

// Example usage:
const res = await getUserInfo(['name', 'email', 'height']);
// res is of type: { name: string, email: string, height: string }[]

const res2 = await getUserInfo(['name']);
// res2 is of type: { name: string }[]
```

Comment: I pasted this code as is into my VSCode, and i have all three options for res and res2 as well. I had something like this for my scenario with Partial, but this happened to me as well. I'd like to restrict the resulting keys. Or maybe i do something wrong here.

Comment: note that this is unsafe with the `as` since you do want the partial user.

Answer (score 0):

based on @jonrsharpe's lead, i transformed that code to fit setup in my question:

```
type Keys = "name" | "email" | "height";

type Result<T extends readonly Keys[]> = {
    [Key in T[number]]: string | number | boolean | null;
};

function getUserInfo<T extends readonly Keys[]>(keys: T): Result<T> {
    return keys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        // ... Some logic here
        return acc; 
    }, {} as Result<T>);
}

const res = getUserInfo(["height"]);
// res will only have 'height' prop here
```

The basic idea explained in that post seems to be to let the compiler know for sure that the input of `getUserInfo` is known at compile time.

**Update:**
Well it turns out, it works the same if I omit the readonly modifiers:

```
type Keys = "name" | "email" | "height";

type Result<T extends Keys[]> = {
    [Key in T[number]]: string | number | boolean | null;
};

function getUserInfo<T extends Keys[]>(keys: T): Result<T> {
    return keys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        // ... Some logic here
        return acc; 
    }, {} as Result<T>);
}

const res = getUserInfo(["height", "name"]);
// res will only have 'height' and 'name' prop here
```

So the magic sauce seems to be `T[number]` which i guess then restrict the keys to be from the keys prop. At least in TS version 5.3.2.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to generate a type using Record.

```
const keys = ['name', 'email', 'height'] as const;

type MyObject = Record<typeof keys[number], string>;

const myObject: MyObject = {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  height: '',
};

console.log(myObject);
```